# Model Implementation That Calls RESTful API

Tags: design-patterns, objective-c, web-services

I am working on a ground-up rebuild for an app that has a relatively simple purpose. Users can view/favorite entities that are backed by a RESTful API. I own both the client code as well as the API. For this rebuild, I wanted to refactor the networking code out of my view controllers and hopefully move my codebase toward being more understandable by yet to be hired other developers. A few assumptions/goals I had going in.

1. View Controllers should neither know about, nor care where/how models are getting their data.
2. Models should be able to update/build themselves.
3. Any client used to talk to an API should be relatively "pluggable". I use a subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` from AFNetworking now, but who knows if that is the case a year from now.
4. Singleton API clients with delegate callbacks have caused race condition issues for me in the past.
5. I'd like to unit test as much of this as possible.

I *think* I have achieved most of my goals. However, being a relative noob, there is surely room for improvement around either architecture or implementation. Much love in advance for any wisdom. On to it.

## Protocols

### GTCommunicator.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//Class Forward declaration
@class GTBaseEntity;

//Protocol forward declaration. Needed as there is a circular reference
@protocol GTAPICommunicatorDelegate;

@protocol GTAPICommunicator <NSObject>

@required

@property (weak) id<GTAPICommunicatorDelegate> delegate;

- (void)fetchOne:(GTBaseEntity *)entity;
- (void)fetchMany:(NSArray *)arrayOfEntities;

@end
```

### GTAPICommunicatorDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//Protocol forward declaration. Needed as there is a circular reference
@protocol GTAPICommunicator;

@protocol GTAPICommunicatorDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)client:(id<GTAPICommunicator>)client didFetchRawEntityDictionary:(NSDictionary *)entityDictionary;
- (void)client:(id<GTAPICommunicator>)client didFetchRawEntities:(NSArray *)rawEntityArray;

@required
- (void)client:(id<GTAPICommunicator>)client didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

### GTAPIBackedBaseEntity.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

//Forward Class Declaration
@class GTBaseEntity;

@protocol GTAPIBackedBaseEntity <NSObject>

@required

@property (nonatomic, strong) GTAPIClient *client;

-(void)fetch:(void (^)(NSError *errorOrNil, GTBaseEntity *returnedEntity))completionBlock;

@end
```

## API Client

### GTAPIClient.h

```
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"

//Protocol import
#import "GTAPICommunicator.h"

@interface GTAPIClient : AFHTTPSessionManager <GTAPICommunicator>

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

### GTAPIClient.m

```
#import "GTAPIClient.h"

//Models
#import "GTBaseEntity.h"

//Protocols
#import "GTAPICommunicatorDelegate.h"

@implementation GTAPIClient
@synthesize delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];

    if (self) {
        self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];

        [self.requestSerializer setValue:kGTAPIKey forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GT-API-Key"];
        [self.requestSerializer setValue:[self realUser] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GT-Real-User"];

        NSLog(@"API User: %@", [self realUser]);

    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Entity Fetching
- (void)fetchOne:(GTBaseEntity *)entity
{

    //Check to make sure the entity passed in is valid and exists
    if (!entity || ![self isValidEntity:entity]) {
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"The object passed into fetchOne is not a GTBaseEntity"];
    }

    //Construct the path
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", entity.type, entity._id];

    //Call the API
    [self GET:path
   parameters:nil

      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        //All good, send the raw responseObject back to the delegate. Might want to actually check to make sure this is an NSDictionary
        [self.delegate client:self didFetchRawEntityDictionary:responseObject];
    }

      failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        //Things went badly, send the error back to the delegate
        [self.delegate client:self didFailWithError:error];
    }];

}
```

## Model

### GTBaseEntity.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GTEntityType) {
    GTEntityTypeProject,
    GTEntityTypePerson,
    GTEntityTypeAgency,
    GTEntityTypeOffice,
    GTEntityTypeVendor,
    GTEntityTypeCategory,
    GTEntityTypeProtest,
    GTEntityTypeIDV,
    GTEntityTypeActivity,
    GTEntityTypeUnknown
};

#import "GTAPIClient.h"

//Protocols
#import "GTAPICommunicatorDelegate.h"
#import "GTAPIBackedBaseEntity.h"

@interface GTBaseEntity : NSObject <GTAPICommunicatorDelegate, GTAPIBackedBaseEntity>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *timestamp;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) GTEntityType entityType;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIImage *icon;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIImage *selectedIcon;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *NTI;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *undefinedProperties;

@property (copy) void (^completionBlock)(NSError *errorOrNil, GTBaseEntity *returnedEntity);

@property (nonatomic, strong) GTAPIClient<GTAPICommunicator> *client;

//Returns a subclass of GTBaseEntity, dependent on the passed in dictionary
+ (instancetype)entityFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;

@end
```

### GTBaseEntity.m

```
#import "GTBaseEntity.h"

//Subclasses
#import "GTProjectEntity.h"
#import "GTPersonEntity.h"
#import "GTAgencyEntity.h"
#import "GTOfficeEntity.h"
#import "GTVendorEntity.h"
#import "GTCategoryEntity.h"
#import "GTIDVEntity.h"
#import "GTProtestEntity.h"
#import "GTActivityEntity.h"

//API Clients
#import "GTAPIClient.h"

@implementation GTBaseEntity


//Some methods removed for ease of reading

#pragma mark - Fetching
-(void)fetch:(void (^)(NSError *errorOrNil, GTBaseEntity *returnedEntity))completionBlock
{
    //Set the passsed in completionBlock for use later on the delegate callbacks
    self.completionBlock = completionBlock;

    //Get an API Client, set the delegate to self, and tell the client to fetch
    self.client.delegate = self;
    [self.client fetchOne:self];

}

#pragma mark - Overridden Getters
- (GTAPIClient *)client
{
    if (_client) return _client;
    else {
        //Instantiate new client with url string constant
        NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kGTAPIURLString];
        _client = [[GTAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:apiURL];
        return _client;
    }
}

#pragma mark - GTAPICommunicatorDelegate Methods

- (void)client:(id<GTAPICommunicator>)client didFetchRawEntityDictionary:(NSDictionary *)entityDictionary
{
    //Update self with the new values in rawDictionary
    [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:entityDictionary];

    //Fire completionBlock with reference to self
    if (self.completionBlock) {
        self.completionBlock(nil,self);
        self.completionBlock = nil;
    }

    //Fire notification for other things that may care about this entity being updated
    NSNotification *entityFetchedNotification = [NSNotification notificationWithName:kGTEntityFetchedNotification object:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:entityFetchedNotification];
}


- (void)client:(id<GTAPICommunicator>)client didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error.code == 404) {
        //Try to load from cache if available. If so, fire self.completionBlock with cachedEntity else fire completionBlock with error

    } else {
        //Nothing worked, just fire completionBlock with error
        if (self.completionBlock) {
            self.completionBlock(error,self);
            self.completionBlock = nil;
        }
    }

}

@end
```

## View Controller (Example)

### GTViewControlller.m

```
#import "GTViewController.h"

//Models
#import "GTBaseEntity.h"

@interface GTViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) GTBaseEntity *entity;

@end


@implementation GTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // This is an example, merely to show how a GTBaseEntity might be used within a VC
    [self refreshEntity];

}

- (void)refreshEntity
{
    //Assume self.entity was injected on init and is valid
    GTBaseEntity *currentDisplayedEntity = self.entity;

    [currentDisplayedEntity fetch:^(NSError *errorOrNil, GTBaseEntity *returnedEntity) {
        if (errorOrNil == nil) {
            //Do something fun, like update the UI
        } else {
            //Alert the user that something is wacky.
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: I'm going to say upon first glance that this looks overly complicated, and the fact that we're using protocol-delegate pattern AND completion blocks AND notification center is a massive big red warning flag to me.  With that said, when I have opportunity to look through this, I'll give you a review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I'm going to focus my answer on the outermost level of your code--the level which I'd be dealing with if I'm one of your yet-to-be-hired developers.  Hopefully, if the code works, no one will have to touch the inner levels, but this code is written with the intent to be re-used over and over, so the part that the end-user developer is touching all the time should work well, right?

As it stands, your code is suffering from a major identity crisis.  You have the delegate/protocol pattern AND completion blocks AND notification center.  I'm not trying to be offensive, but it looks like someone who barely knew what they were doing pieced this together with lots of StackOverflow research.  These three choices largely overlap each other, and rarely do you want to be using all three.  Particularly when choosing between delegate/protocol pattern and completion blocks, these overlap basically entirely and there's no particularly good reason to mix and match between the two.

But mixing and matching has resulted in a completion block which returns a reference to the object which you sent the completion block to... which is completely unnecessary.

If we were using the delegate pattern however, sending a reference to `self` makes sense in the delegate method.

I personally vastly prefer the protocol/delegate pattern to completion blocks and I think it makes it much easier to write cleaner code.  Though this is a personal preference.  You can stick with the completion block if you want, but you should take the self reference out.

If you stick with the completion block, the self reference can be eliminated and still access that variable in that block as such:

```
__weak typeof(currentDisplayedEntity) weakEntity = currentDisplayedEntity;

[currentDisplayedEntity fetch:^(NSError *errorOrNil) {
    if (errorOrNil == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Entity: %@", weakEntity);
    } else {
        //Alert the user that something is wacky.
    }
}];
```

However, what seems most likely isn't that the user needs a reference to the entity so much as they need references to objects you've set as properties on the entity class.  If this is the case, I think it might be best to pass these individually into the completion block.

If you want to change this to the protocol/delegate pattern, which again, is my personal preference, and I think it leans to ultimately cleaner code, it'd look something like this:

```
@protocol GTBaseEntityDelegate

@required - (void)entityDidFinishFetching:(GTBaseEntity *)entity;
@required - (void)entityDidFetchFromCache:(GTBaseEntity *)entity;
@optional - (void)entityFetchDidFailWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

**EDIT:** I believe this was posted yesterday when the site was undergoing maintenance as the last bit of my answer isn't here.  I'll complete this soon.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I am going to go with your suggestion and switch to deleate/protocol only. One question on codereview expected behavior - should I repost my updated code as an edit to my question? Or do I just go on my merry way, seemingly a little wiser?

Comment: And accepted answer is fine.  If you want further review on your now updated code, you can always post another question.